# Friction proportional to parallel force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Friction is a result of Newton's 3rd law right? When an object slides across another, the bumps in the things collide and there is an equal and opposite force that acts on the object that is sliding. If this is true, thy is the equation for friction F = μFn? This is not taking into account the input parallel force acting on the object. Why is this? Thanks.